# C++ Non-Template Used as Template - Nested Template Classes

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, typename

I know people have asked similar questions in this area, but I can not seem to find a solution to my exact problem. I have a `LinkedList` and `LinkedListIterator` class structured as so.

```
template <typename T>
class LinkedList
{
public:
  template <typename NodeType>
  class LinkedListIterator
  {
    public:
      const LinkedListIterator<NodeType>& operator++();
  }
};
```

I am trying to implement the `operator++()` function in a separate file and my attempt is as follows.

```
template <typename T>
template <typename NodeType>
const typename LinkedList<T>::LinkedListIterator<NodeType>&
LinkedList<T>::LinkedListIterator<NodeType>::operator++()
{
 // Implementation here
}
```

Now when I try to use this class, my compiler throws an error saying **non-template ‘LinkedListIterator’ used as template**. Now I know I have to use `typename` in the definition of this function since I have dependent scopes occurring. But I can not seem to be able to fix this. I do not understand how this is seen as `non-template`.

Comment: Compiles fine here https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Pr366s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add template keyword before LinkedListIterator so compiler knows it is a template and not e.g. a field

```
template <typename T>
template <typename NodeType>
const typename LinkedList<T>::template LinkedListIterator<NodeType>&
LinkedList<T>::LinkedListIterator<NodeType>::operator++()
{
  // Implementation here                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
}
```

Comment: Thanks that seemed to do the trick. But I have a follow up question. I thought that was the point of including the typename keyword? Do you mind explaining why I need both the typename keyword and template and when I use each individually?

Comment: Compiler explains a bit when you omit _typename_:
`error: need ‘typename’ before ‘LinkedList<T>::LinkedListIterator<NodeType>’ because ‘LinkedList<T>’ is a dependent scope
 const LinkedList<T>::template LinkedListIterator<NodeType>&`